# Find String in subDoc MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hi friends I'm trying to find in my subDoc category string matching

Here is the code:

```
router.get('/:_categoryName', (req, res, next) => {
    Malgezot.findOne({ 'items.category': req.params._categoryName  }, (err, malgezot) => {
        if(err) return res.render('body/category', {info: ''});
        console.log(malgezot);
      });
});
```

But the results is all of the items!

I also tried:

```
router.get('/:_categoryName', (req, res, next) => { 
    Malgezot.find({'items': { 'category': req.params.categoryName }}, (err, malgezot) => { 
        if(err) return res.render('body/category', {info: ''}); 
        console.log(malgezot); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Could you post your schema also?

Comment: Yes
https://paste.ofcode.org/fRB4rJwPzSK8XeqSnSb9GR

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with 'items.category'. Are you definitely hitting this endpoint?

Comment: can you provide a sample of structure stored in db ?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in form of object then query should be :

```
router.get('/:_categoryName', (req, res) => {
    const { _categoryName } = req.params;

    Malgezot.findOne({
        'items.category': _categoryName
    }).then((data) => {
        if (data) {
            res.status(200).json(data)
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Internal server error'
        });
    });

});
```

Or if your data in form of array then your query should be:

```
    router.get('/:_categoryName', (req, res) => {
    const { _categoryName } = req.params;

    Malgezot.findOne({
        item : { $in : [{ category: _categoryName  }] }
    }).then((data) => {
        if (data) {
            res.status(200).json(data)
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Internal server error'
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: I fix that:

router.get('/:_categoryName', (req, res, next) => { 
    Malgezot.findOne({ 'items.category': req.params._categoryName}, (err, malgezot) => { 
        if(err) return res.render('body/category', {info: ''}); 
        let results = malgezot.items.filter((m)=>m.category === req.params._categoryName)[0]; 
        return res.render('body/category', {items: results, category: req.params._categoryName}); 
    }); 
});

But I use HBS express 
And when I make {{#each}}
I get 8  empty objects
The result is only 2